# ENTER DATE WITH TIME STAMP IN MS-EXCEL

Tags: excel, datetime

I am using CONCATENATE funciton to group data in a cell in which i have to include date and timestamp. i need to run some batches of data in my database as part of my daily routine. i need the date and timestamp at most importantly as that will help in minimizing my work load.

DATA
CELL A3:    2012-07-31 18:00:00
CELL B3:    (521976, 521977, 521978, 521979)
FORMULA:    =CONCATENATE("update tbl_content_master set start_date='",A3,"' where content_id in ",B3,";")
RESULT:     update tbl_content_master set start_date='41121.75' where content_id in (521976, 521977, 521978, 521979);

ISSUE 
FROM FORMULA  start_date='",A3,"'   i.e. 2012-07-31 18:00:00 (date with time stamp)
FROM RESULT   start_date='41121.75' i.e. 41121.75 (decimal format)

PRESENT RESULT:  update tbl_content_master set start_date='41121.75' where content_id in (521976, 521977, 521978, 521979);

REQUIRED RESULT: update tbl_content_master set start_date='2012-07-31 18:00:00' where content_id in (521976, 521977, 521978, 521979);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the TEXT function: TEXT(*cell w/date*, "*format string*")

```
=CONCATENATE("update tbl_content_master set start_date='",TEXT(A3,"YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"),"' where content_id in ",B3,";")
```

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for the help..! after posting my question in the form i had tried my hands on my own script though its too lengthy finally it works!   ..what i  did was i had gathered yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss from 6 different cells and used the concatenate operator. finally it got worked..